# Store SVN password in gnome-keyring

Tags: 18.04, svn, keyrings

I can see other questions about how to disable GNOME keyring for SVN. I have the opposite problem and cannot enable it.  I can see answers for other distros, but they don't seem entirely to apply - e.g. there is mention of GNOME_KEYRING_SOCKET but I can't see any sign that it's set.

Here's data about my system and what I've tried:

1. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
2. svn --version: 1.9.7 (r2800392), reports Gnome Keyring in list of credential caches
3. ~/.subversion/config has `[auth] password-stores = gnome-keyring`
4. ~/.subversion/servers has `[global] store-passwords = yes`
5. ~/.subversion/servers has `[global] store-plaintext-passwords = no` and this setting is working, which indicates I am editing the right config file
6. Gnome keyring daemon is running and works for both SSH and Evolution

Please can anyone suggest what I am missing or something else I can try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, inspired by a [similar issue](https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/6455#issuecomment-384371758) for an entirely different program.

Ubuntu 18.04 removed a default package that was present in earlier releases.  The solution is to put that package back:

```
sudo aptitude install libgnome-keyring0
```